# Angular: how do I call a scope method on state change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

the angular UI-Router events for `stateChangeSuccess` etc are fired at the `rootScope` level and so mostly the code related to these events reside in the `RootCtrl`

I have two states home and about, with `HomeCtrl` and `AboutCtrl`

on `stateChange` to `'about'` I want to call a method in `AboutCtrl` ... how can I achieve this?

NOTE: I can call `$scope.RootCtrlMethod` as the `stateChangeSuccess` code is written in `RootCtrl`, but can't do the same for `AboutCtrl`.

example: `RootCtrl` :

```
function($rootScope, $scope){
    $scope.someFun = function(){
        console.log("called");
    }

    $rootScope.$on('routeChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, fromState,...){
    if(toState.name == '/'){
        $scope.someFun();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick here would be to hook that event exactly on the **`$scope`**, not on the `*$rootScope*`:

```
//$rootScope.$on('routeChangeSuccess', 
$scope.$on('routeChangeSuccess', 
  function(event, toState, fromState,...){
    if(toState.name == '/'){
        $scope.someFun();
        }
     }
```

And now we have access to any method defined on our $scope.

But, in this case, we need to be sure, that we will clear up that hook

```
var removeMe = $scope.$on('routeChangeSuccess', ...
$scope.$on("$destroy", removeMe);
```

So, once our $scope is destroyed, we won't create memory leaks.

Comment: you are suggesting to have this code in AboutCtrl ?

Comment: Exactly this is what I suggest. You would have access to all the stuff related to that controller, and if properly cleared.. no memory leak will happen to your app. If you want to have that feature global.. you should move any method implementation to some "singleton"  - service. No reference to a `$scope` ... because if there  is no $scope (different controller) than there is no way how to call its method.